# Run as different user under FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

Is there a way in FreeBSD to (being root) run a command as unprivileged user, like nobody? Kind of like reverse of sudo. Oh and considering that 'nobody' has /usr/sbin/nologin as shell - so **su** is not an option.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

sudo will allow you to run a command as another user.

```
sudo -u nobody <command>
```

will run  as nobody, even if their login shell is not available.

Comment: tip for bomboze: "man sudo" . do it once.

Comment: Note that `sudo` is a Port (`security/sudo` in the Ports tree), not in the distribution as default.

Answer (score 66):

You can `su` to an account with the `nologin` shell if you use the `-m` option.

Example:

```
su -m cthulhu -c '/usr/bin/scorpion-stare'
```

will run the SCORPION STARE command-line utility as the user `cthulhu`.

Comment: +1 because this is an answer that does NOT require the installation of an extra binary! And works out of the box.

Comment: What is the -c for?

Comment: @Chris That tells it what command you want to run as that user.

Comment: @KrisAnderson This is not true. `-c` is not [su(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?su) flag. The first argument which is not recognised by su(1) is the first argument passed to sh(1). So effectively you get `sh -c '/usr/bin/scorpion-stare'`. See [sh(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sh) for details.