# Execute under different user on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I am logged in as root in a freebsd (10) box and I am trying to execute a script (or any command) as another user, but I get: "su: Sorry"

```
root@vm ~ # whoami
root
root@vm ~ # cat /etc/passwd
#...
myuser:*:1001:1001:my name:/home/myuser:/usr/local/bin/bash
#...
root@vm ~ # su -m myuser -c '/bin/ls /tmp'
su: Sorry
root@vm ~ # su -m myuser
su: Sorry
```

Answer (score 2):

su - is used to elevate access level. for example myuser executes as root. 
You are trying it reverse way. myuser is not member of "wheel" group.

Also it looks like root is not am member of "wheel" too. 
post what do you have in passwd for root?

[Run as different user under FreeBSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285658/run-as-different-user-under-freebsd)

Comment: By default it is used to do that, but it is by no means the only way to use su. In the question that you link to there is acualy an answer that describes what what this user wants to do with su.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it: I installed the port `security/sudo`, and then I used `sudo -u myuser`.